# MySQL - How should i index this table?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, group-by, query-optimization

I have a table where user's tv shows library is stored and i would like to improve it

The table contains the following columns:

- `USER_ID`
- `SHOW_ID`
- `STATUS`
- `PROGRESS` | Last episode watched
- `IS_FAVORITE`
- `RATING`

I have the following index:

- `USER_ID & SHOW_ID` | Primary
- `USER_ID` | Needed for foreign key
- `SHOW_ID` | Needed for foreign key
- `USER_ID & STATUS`
- `USER_ID & IS_FAVORITE`
- `SHOW_ID & STATUS`
- `SHOW_ID & IS_FAVORITE`

I have about 20M rows, data weight about 750MB, index weight about 2GB in total about 2.75GB
I think that there are too many indexes but maybe they are really need to improve performance, should i leave it like that or should i remove the last 4 indexes and why?

Comment: It depends on your queries, what are your most run queries, if those queries are using these indexes then leave them as is, otherwise remove

Comment: Indexing depends on queris which you are executing. Do you know your most common queries on this table?

Comment: This is worth reading: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: The two FK (single column) keys are redundant and can be removed.  The FKs will pick up on the other indexes as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The size of your indexes sure seems quite large compared to the data.

However the answer to your question depends widely on the queries that you are running against this table. You should know your queries, so you can analyze them one by one : if you find an index that none of the queries use, then drop it.

If you don't know your queries, and you are running MySQL 5.6 or higher, you can use the [`PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html) to access indexes IO statistics (since the last time the database restarted). This can be used to detect unused indexes, like :

```
SELECT 
    object_schema,
    object_name,
    index_name
FROM 
    performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage 
WHERE
    index_name IS NOT NULL
   AND count_star = 0
ORDER BY object_schema, object_name;
```

See [this discussion](http://www.markleith.co.uk/2011/04/18/monitoring-table-and-index-io-with-performance_schema/) for more information. However be careful when using this method : you might have a monthly or quaterly query that relies on an oddball index, that might not show up on a short term analyzis.

Comment: Beware of detecting "Unused" queries -- You might have a monthly Delete that needs that oddball index.  Remove the index and you will be in deep doo-doo.

Comment: @RickJames : right, thanks for pointing it out, I added a warning in my answer. Anyway, IMO the best option is still to know which query you run so you can start your analyzis from there instead of the other way around